# Can we say "could you swim a loop?" to mean to swim from one end to the other end and then get back to where you start?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

According to my research, "**to swim a lap**" means to swim **lengthwise** from one end to the other end of a pool.

In Vietnamese, we say "**could you swim a circle/ a loop of the pool?**" (literally translated) to mean to swim from one end to the other end and then get back to where you start.

So, when I swam 2 laps, I swam 2 lengths of a pool but it does not imply to swim from one end to the other end and then get back to where you start.

Can we say "**could you swim a loop/ a circle?**" to mean to swim from one end to the other end and then get back to where you start?

Comment: **If two people are in the same lane**, pool rules on the wall will often say: **Swim in a circle**. Obviously, when you do that, you are also swimming a lap. Loop is **not used** to describe swimming laps, either with or without another person in your lane. Your drawing should show lanes in a pool for this purpose.

Comment: @Lambie, when you say "**swim in a circle**", people might think you are circling in the middle of the pool and not touching the 2 ends of the pool.

Comment: It is quite annoying to not believe someone who takes the time to patiently explain it and who clearly know what she is talking about.  Now, you can see **for yourself**.

Comment: @Lambie  To a layperson, such as myself, if someone told me to swim in a circle I might well think to swim round and round in the middle of a pool which didn't have lane markers or floaters (whatever those things are called!).

Comment: @Mari-LouA There are only two ways to share a lane: split the lane or swim in a circle. And that includes in the UK: https://www.sports-fitness.co.uk/blog/lane-sharing-etiquette-swimming-pool You might consider doing me honor of reading my links.,

Comment: https://www.bannatyne.co.uk/uploaded/cookridge_timetable_latest_07.03.18.pdf If the your lane has more than two swimmers, you will need to circle swim. I explained very clearly that this is about swimming in a lane.

Comment: If I couldn't read a link, (left my mobile somewhere) or had no access to the Internet I would think that swim in a circle meant what I said earlier. I said "if a layperson" because I acknowledge you know your stuff and I did actually watch the video, but what I'm trying to say is that the expression could be easily misinterpreted by a normal i.e. layperson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swimming from one end to the other would be called swimming a **length**.

Swimming from one end to the other and then back to the start would be called **swimming two lengths**. If you said, "Could you swim two lengths of the pool" it would be understood to be asking to swim back to the starting point.

A lap would probably mean two lengths to me, but I'd use the term more in a running race around a track. To others it means one length. It could also (in context) mean once around the edge of the pool.

Comment: No, this website says "** if you swim from one side of the pool to the other it counts as one lap (and a length is the same as a lap).**" (https://swimcompetitive.com/swimming-guides/what-is-a-lap-in-swimming/).

Comment: That's not how people at my gym use the word. Perhaps its another British/American thing.

Comment: This website says "A lap refers to swimming from one end of the pool to the next. Without a doubt, it’s one end of the pool to the other. It’s not back and forth." https://evanmorrison.com/swim/posts/lap-vs-length-pool-swimming/

Comment: This website says "One lap in swimming is defined as the distance from one end of the pool to the other end of the pool. This is also known as a length. Despite popular belief, a lap is not down and back." https://athleteapproved.com/one-lap-in-swimming-defined/

Comment: Looks like I'm with the "popular belief" -- ie the common way that language is used by native speakers, rather then the technical meaning in competitive swimming (I'm not a competitive swimmer - far from it)

Answer (score 0):

> WHAT IS CIRCLE SWIMMING?

> Circle swimming is a way for multiple
> swimmers to swim laps in a single lane. The main keys to circle
> swimming are to stay on the right side of the lane and to be mindful
> of your lane mates.
>
> [circle swimming](https://protips.dickssportinggoods.com/sports-and-activities/water-sports/pro-tips-guide-to-circle-swimming)

The term loop is **not used**.

YOUTUBE video from the US MASTERS

Circle swimming

[US MASTERS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-7-LGjas5g)

When you swim in a circle in a lane, you are also swimming a lap.
This is used in American English and British English.